# How to change the range slider marker?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rangeslider

I have to achieve this: 
[Range Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfQ2j.png)

I have done the range slider part but I am facing issues while changing the marker over range slider. Even I am providing the image src : "https://png.icons8.com/metro/52/000000/sort-down.png".

I am adding my work upto where I have completed.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  width: 30%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 128, 0, 1));
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.slider:hover {
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 128, 0, 1));
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
  background: url('contrasticon.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
  background: url('contrasticon.png');
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  
</div>
```

Comment: you can find how to customize range btn here: https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `appearance: none;` on the slider thumb to use a custom image.
Have a look:

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  width: 30%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 128, 0, 1));
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.slider:hover {
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 128, 0, 1));
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
  background: url('https://png.icons8.com/metro/52/000000/sort-down.png');
  background-size: 16px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 -4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 0;
  background: url('https://png.icons8.com/metro/52/000000/sort-down.png');
    background-size: 16px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 -4px;

  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  
</div>
```

Now feel free to change the image property like size, rotation, z-index whatever you need

Answer (score 1):

You can try a pure CSS solution where you can easily control the arrow (size, color, position) without the need of image:

```css
.slider {
  margin:50px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 128, 0, 1));
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,#000 49%,transparent 50%) top left/50% 15px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,#000 49%,transparent 50%) top right/50% 15px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,#000 49%,transparent 50%) top left/50% 15px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,#000 49%,transparent 50%) top right/50% 15px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  
</div>
```